# How To Implement Custom Scroll Buttons In Bootstrap Modal Body

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want to implement a custom scroll up & down button outside the Bootstrap 4 modal but I have no idea how to achieve this functionality. I has hidden the scroll bar using (::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}) property to enhance the modal body design.

On PC we can scroll using the mouse but some people may get confused so that's why I want to add two custom up & down buttons. (Check out the image I attached)

Is it possible to achieve the functionality using javascript?

[![My project website with buttons

```css
.modal-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.modal-body P {
  color: red;
}

.modal.left_modal .modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  width: 450px;
  max-width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}

.modal.left_modal .modal-content {
  height: 100vh !important;
}

.modal.left_modal.fade .modal-dialog{
  left: -50%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal.left_modal.fade.show .modal-dialog{
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.modal_outer .modal-body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    
<button class="btn  btn-primary  mt-3 float-right" id="modal_view_left" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#get_quote_modal">Open modal</button>


<div class="modal modal_outer left_modal fade" id="get_quote_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" >
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2 class="modal-title">LEFT MODAL</h2>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni numquam accusantium dolore ipsum! Aut distinctio maxime obcaecati, sapiente nisi laudantium dignissimos optio, ea ex quas laboriosam ab officia odit, sequi.</p><br><br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni numquam accusantium dolore ipsum! Aut distinctio maxime obcaecati, sapiente nisi laudantium dignissimos optio, ea ex quas laboriosam ab officia odit, sequi.</p><br><br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni numquam accusantium dolore ipsum! Aut distinctio maxime obcaecati, sapiente nisi laudantium dignissimos optio, ea ex quas laboriosam ab officia odit, sequi.</p><br><br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni numquam accusantium dolore ipsum! Aut distinctio maxime obcaecati, sapiente nisi laudantium dignissimos optio, ea ex quas laboriosam ab officia odit, sequi.</p><br><br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni numquam accusantium dolore ipsum! Aut distinctio maxime obcaecati, sapiente nisi laudantium dignissimos optio, ea ex quas laboriosam ab officia odit, sequi.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">cancel</button>
        </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn8F4.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn8F4.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely possible. In the snippet you will find the basic setup needed to achieve this.

Though I did not implement scrolling more on each click or styles of any kind, you will have to add that yourself. Read the scrolltop value of your modal content and add your desired number, this has to happen in every click to set the correct new scroll value.

[javascript scroll documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll)

```css
.modal-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.modal-body P {
  color: red;
}

.modal.left_modal .modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  width: 450px;
  max-width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}

.modal.left_modal .modal-content {
  height: 100vh !important;
}

.modal.left_modal.fade .modal-dialog{
  left: -50%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal.left_modal.fade.show .modal-dialog{
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.modal_outer .modal-body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    
<button class="btn  btn-primary  mt-3 float-right" id="modal_view_left" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#get_quote_modal">Open modal</button>


<div class="modal modal_outer left_modal fade" id="get_quote_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" >
  <button id="scrollDown">v</button>
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2 class="modal-title">LEFT MODAL</h2>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni numquam accusantium dolore ipsum! Aut distinctio maxime obcaecati, sapiente nisi laudantium dignissimos optio, ea ex quas laboriosam ab officia odit, sequi.</p><br><br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni numquam accusantium dolore ipsum! Aut distinctio maxime obcaecati, sapiente nisi laudantium dignissimos optio, ea ex quas laboriosam ab officia odit, sequi.</p><br><br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni numquam accusantium dolore ipsum! Aut distinctio maxime obcaecati, sapiente nisi laudantium dignissimos optio, ea ex quas laboriosam ab officia odit, sequi.</p><br><br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni numquam accusantium dolore ipsum! Aut distinctio maxime obcaecati, sapiente nisi laudantium dignissimos optio, ea ex quas laboriosam ab officia odit, sequi.</p><br><br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni numquam accusantium dolore ipsum! Aut distinctio maxime obcaecati, sapiente nisi laudantium dignissimos optio, ea ex quas laboriosam ab officia odit, sequi.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">cancel</button>
        </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
let btn = document.getElementById('scrollDown');
let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body'); // returns array

btn.onclick = function(e) {
    elem[0].scroll(0, 1000); // scrolls inside modal body
};
</script>
```

Relevant script:

```js
    let btn = document.getElementById('scrollDown');
    let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body'); // returns array - you can use ID instead

    btn.onclick = function(e) {
        // if you set an id on the modal body, you do not need elem[0], just elem
        elem[0].scroll(0, 1000); // scrolls inside modal body
    };
```